# svn change revision from single number to major.minor

Tags: svn, release, revision

I'm trying to change svn revision number due to obtain a major.minor.release format.
In my configuration svn revision number is incremented by  one for each commit.
It should be possible to change it ?

I'm studying how to do this using perl but it would be gold for me if you could suggest a kind of ace in the hole solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, what you might want to do is [tag the specific revisions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.branchmerge.tags.html) corresponding to your releases

Answer (score 0):

Do not **mix** *version control numbers* and *release numbers*. Just don't abuse it this way.

The latest when you switch RCS from say, subversion to git, you are screwed. **Seriously, do your version numbering manually.** At most, include the subversion revision number as a postfix build indicator.

What do you gain from tieing your release version numbers to your RCS system internal numbering? These numbers essentially are just **unique ids** for the system, but *not software version numbers*. They are **commit numbers**, so don't mess with that.

Answer (score 0):

No, ***you cannot change the SVN revision number***, and neither should you.

Under the hood, SVN makes a (lazy) copy of the whole repository tree each time you check in something. This copy is stored and accessed by an ID, and that ID is referred to as the ***revision number***. It's a piece of information ***internal to your repository***, and except for it being needed to refer to a specific revision, the value of this ID should be of no concern to you.

Which ***version number*** your piece of software is delivered to customers with is something that's decided ***externally from the repository*** and independently from the number of checkins into the repository. (Your customers do not care whether you needed a hundred checkins to implement the shiny new features and iron out those nasty bugs, or a thousand of them.)

It is your task as a developer to ***make the connection between an internal revision number and some externally used version number***. This is done by tagging (or branching, if you will plan to have several minor releases from that major release). If there's a specific revision that you want to release as version 1.0, just copy this revision to something like `tags/releases/1.0`. (Note that this even allows you to mix source files from different revisions for a single release. Just selectively update them to specific revisions and when you have the state that you want tag off that mixed working copy.)

The [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) explains all this. Do yourself a favor and take a few hours to read through it. This will pay off within days.